# Is the validity of a foreign driving license for a new UK resident 12 months from issue of RP or arrival?

Tags: united-kingdom, driving-license

> If you get your provisional license during that first 12 months, you are not required to show L-plates during that first 12 months (the time that your foreign licence is still valid). You also don't need to be accompanied, and you can drive on motorways (again, just during the first 12 months). After that first 12 months, you must show L-plates and be accompanied, so it's best to start the process as soon as possible.

What will be triggering date of these 12 months?  When  the residence permit (RP) is issued or when the resident reached the UK (which could be a few weeks or months later than the RP issue date).

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to explain what "RP" means please.  Is it "residence permit"?

Comment: @MartinBonner I took the liberty.  Muhammad, I also presumed that the first paragraph is quoted from elsewhere, so I put it in a quotation block.  If I misinterpreted anything, please advise.

Comment: @phoog The text you have quoted doesn't read like something from an official website.  I think it is the OP's interpretation of what he has read.

Comment: @Martin Bonner it doesn't.  But it is also not written in the same style as (the original version of) the second paragraph.  So I presume that it was quoted from an unofficial website.

Comment: @MartinBonner the source appears to be [Can I use my international driving license instead of a provisional one to pass a driving test?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/1263/2440)

Answer (score 5):

The 12 months period starts on the date you entered the UK on your visa.

From [gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/driving-nongb-licence/y/a-resident-of-great-britain/full-car-and-or-motorcycle/any-other-country):

> You can drive in Great Britain on your full, valid driving licence for 12 months **from when you became resident**

(my emphasis)

Comment: I think that it leads naturally from the fact that having the provisional doesn't actually affect the entitlement to drive without plates. When you begin residence in the UK, you are allowed to drive for 12 months on a foreign licence. Getting the provisional licence doesn't extend that period.

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/driving-nongb-licence/y/a-resident-of-great-britain/full-car-and-or-motorcycle/any-other-country

Comment: I have edited the answer to incorporate the link that @MJeffryes found, and extracted the relevant quote.  If you like the change, please approve it.  If not, feel free to discard it.

Comment: Original comment on requesting reference deleted and upvoted answer.